# How we can select a string up to specific character in php? NB:without using explode()

Tags: php

How we can select a string up to specific character in php?

ie I have a string `Wednesday 16-January-2013`. I need to get only up to first space.

ie output should be `Wednesday`.

I done it using explode,

```
<?php
explode(" ",Wednesday 16-January-2013)
?>
```

But too many explodes and array are permitted in the code. So,

How I can do it **without using explode()**?

Comment: A combination of [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) and [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) can easily do what you need. You just need to find the position of the character you want to select up to, then take the substring from the start to that position. The examples in the manual should easily demonstrate how the two parts are done, then you just need to combine them. Please ensure, when asking questions like this, that you explain [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), we like to see a *little* research effort ;-)

Comment: Why the arbitrary restriction on `explode`?

Comment: @deceze I'm guessing [homework]

Comment: @deceze I m re building an old magento module. So many explode(), array_push() will complex the code.. Thats why...

Comment: `list($day) = explode(' ', $string)` will "complex the code"? Sorry, not following...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of PHP 5.3.0 you can use [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function to return the part of the haystack before the first occurrence of the needle (excluding the needle):

```
$dayOfWeek = strstr('Wednesday 16-January-2013', ' ', true);
echo $dayOfWeek; // prints Wednesday
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `strstr()`:

```
strstr('Wednesday 16-January-2013', ' ', true);
```

The third argument `$before_needle` makes the function return only the part before the space.

See also: [`strstr()`](http://www.php.net/strstr)

Before PHP 5.3 (or if you need to need to branch based on the existence of the space) you would write it like this:

```
$s = 'Wednesday 16-January-2013';
if (($p = strpos($s, ' ')) !== false) {
    echo substr($s, 0, $p);
} else {
    // space wasn't found, bad, bad.
}
```

*If the space is found at the start of the string, it could be considered an error too; in that case, the condition is simply `if ($p = strpos($s, ' ')) {` (i.e. it exists and does not appear at the beginning)*

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `substr` method:

```
substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

You could use it in combination with `strpos` like this:

```
$spacelocation = strpos($originalstring, " ");

if ($spacelocation !== false) {
    $day = substr($originalstring, 0, $spacelocation);
}
```

Comment: You should never rely on the return value of `strpos()` directly like this, you should always check for failures (`=== false`)

Comment: Changed it to check for a original sting without a space.

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
$str = "Wednesday 16-January-2013";
$out = substr( $str, 0, strpos( $str, " " ));
```